# How to make card component align in one row (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui, frontend

i recently start to learn react. I made card component using Material UI for react, but this time i'm going to make it with axios and map().

What i expected was, the cards should be in the same row, not vertical.

This is how the cards look when using axios and map()

[image: Output]

This the frontend code using React, axios, and map()

```
import { makeStyles, withStyles } from "@material-ui/styles";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

//Material UI
import { Grid } from "@material-ui/core";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Card from "@mui/material/Card";
import CardActions from "@mui/material/CardActions";
import CardContent from "@mui/material/CardContent";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  gridContainer: {
    paddingLeft: "40px",
    paddingRight: "40px",
  },
  root: {
    minWidth: 200,
  },
  bullet: {
    display: "inline-block",
    margin: "0 2px",
    transform: "scale(0.8)",
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 14,
  },
  pos: {
    marginBottom: 12,
  },
});

function Home() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [getData, setGetData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/get.php").then((x) => {
      setGetData(x.data);
    });
  }, [getData]);

  return (
    <div>
      {getData.map((x) => {
        return (
          <Grid
            container
            spacing={4}
            className={classes.gridContainer}
            justify="center"
            style={{ marginTop: "80px" }}
          >
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
              <Card className={classes.root} variant="outlined">
                <CardContent>
                  <Typography
                    className={classes.title}
                    color="textSecondary"
                    gutterBottom
                  >
                    Word of the Day
                  </Typography>
                  <Typography className={classes.pos} color="textSecondary">
                    adjective
                  </Typography>
                  <Typography variant="body2" component="p">
                    well meaning and kindly.
                    <br />
                    {'"a benevolent smile"'}
                  </Typography>
                </CardContent>
                <CardActions>
                  <Button size="small">Learn More</Button>
                </CardActions>
              </Card>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
export default Home;
```

Expected output that i looking for before using map() method
[image: Expected Output]

Did i miss some configuration? or styling? grid? container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<Grid container>` should be outside the loop. I would also consider using Material UI v5. Don't forget about `key` prop for looped items.

```
<Grid
  container
  spacing={4}
  className={classes.gridContainer}
  justifyItems="center"
  style={{ marginTop: "80px" }}
>
  {getData.map((x, index) => (          
     <Grid key={index} item xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
       ...
     </Grid>
  )}
</Grid>
```

Comment: this is works, how noob i am :(

Answer (score 0):

Move your Grid Container outside of `map` function. You have to wrap 3 cards inside the Grid Container

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is that you are wrapping each component (using `map()`) inside its own `Grid container`. You need to put the container element outside of the `map()` function so it can work as you expect.

```
return (
    <div>
       <Grid
          container
          spacing={4}
          className={classes.gridContainer}
          justify="center"
          style={{ marginTop: "80px" }}
        >
         {getData.map((x) => {
           return (
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
              <Card className={classes.root} variant="outlined">
                <CardContent>
                  <Typography
                    className={classes.title}
                    color="textSecondary"
                    gutterBottom
                  >
                    Word of the Day
                  </Typography>
                  <Typography className={classes.pos} color="textSecondary">
                    adjective
                  </Typography>
                  <Typography variant="body2" component="p">
                    well meaning and kindly.
                    <br />
                    {'"a benevolent smile"'}
                  </Typography>
                </CardContent>
                <CardActions>
                  <Button size="small">Learn More</Button>
                </CardActions>
              </Card>
            </Grid>
        );
      })}
     </Grid>
    </div>
  );
```